# 1 billion unique strings while inserting millions concurrently

Tags: mysql, database, concurrency, insert, unique

I have over billion unique strings representing usernames and I am adding millions more every few minutes concurrently, over 50% are duplicates. I am currently using a InnoDB table with mySQL. I am using INSERT IGNORE but the server simply cannot keep up with the load of adding millions concurrently (using a extra large CPU EC2 instance). To combat this I am storing the usernames in bulk as the come in and updating the unique table with a service when possible.

I am open to any suggestions I can reasonable setup on a ec2 instance. Maybe redis can achieve what I want to do but I have not used it yet. Can anyone suggest the most efficient way of storing over a billion unique strings while inserting millions more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottleneck is bound to be the sheer number of index lookups every time it checks if the new key is a duplicate, as well as updating the index every time a new row is inserted.  It will need to lock the whole table every time this happens.  This approach eventually won't scale.

I suggest using more than one database instance for this!  That way, these insert operations can run in parallel, across multiple machines and multiple disks.

You would then use some sort of hash to figure out which name would go in which database.  For example, names that begin with `A-D` go in one, `E-H` go in another, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are correct index locking becomes an issue. I had not thought about using multiple databases across machines but it is a very novel solution. It would require me significantly more resources to accomplish but im not adverse to doing that.

Answer (score 0):

1) I recommend [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) over MySQL - you'll generally get better performance. MariaDB can have multiple active masters for writing. It's a drop-in replacement for MySQL, in case you aren't aware of it.

2) Do you have an index on the field you're storing the usernames in?

3) Redis is a great option. I use it a lot and it's very simple and fast. I still can't tell you how well it would perform under that load, but it's very easy to setup and try. You can setup a Redis cluster if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do indeed have an primary index on the usernames but at the concurrent speed i am doing look ups and inserts index locking becomes an issue. Im not sure MariaDB would solve that  likewise with Redis